# No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe in a gradle project

Tags: java, hibernate, gradle, ojdbc

[my project structure, you can see the OJDBC jar added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytTgE.png)

```
apply plugin: 'java'
repositories {
        jcenter()
}

dependencies {

    compile  'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.6.Final'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'


    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

my hibernate config goes like this I dont know whats going wrong even though I added the jar in classpath.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
        <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.drive_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">SYSTEM</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">****</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="Entity.Address"/>
        <mapping class="Entity.Student"/>

    </session-factory>
```

Comment: I had the same error, but in my case it didn't mean what it says. I didn't enter a server address (it was invalid), in that case it says no driver has been found. Maybe that is your case somehow ^^